# Why my branch code is trying to push to master through intellij

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-push

I am working in my own git branch and I want to do my commit to my branch. But it is trying to push the code to master instead. And obviously master is protected. So I cannot directly merge there. How to solve this?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to do that through terminal ? 

git push -u origin [your branch name] ??

if you tried that, what did you get?

Comment: @AliZedan  I get this   -   remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/master.
remote: error: 2 of 2 required status checks are expected. At least 1 approving review is required by reviewers with write access.
To github.com:xxx/project.git
 ! [remote rejected] MY_BRANCH -> master (protected branch hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:xxx/project.git'

Comment: It sure *looks* like you're currently on `master`, but then, I don't use IntelliJ - is the scribbled-over text with the tag-like thingy, that I can't actually read, the current branch? If so, does it have `origin/master` set as its upstream? (Perhaps that's what the greyed text to the right of the green diagonal arrow means?) Meanwhile, for command-line Git: what is your `push.default` setting? If it is `upstream` and the upstream of your current (non-master) branch is `origin/master`, that could explain the command-line result.

Comment: To fix *that*, set the upstream while doing `git push`: set `push.default` to `simple` and re-run the `git push -u origin whateveryoubranchnameis`, or use `git push -u origin whateveryourbranchnameis:whateveryourbranchnameis` (i.e., tell command-line Git explicitly that you want the local branch name used in *both repositories*).

Comment: @torek I am using this command to create the branch git checkout -b my_branch origin/master.  Looks like its somehow tie with master.

Comment: @everalian: Yes: `git checkout -b` or `git switch -c` has a whole bunch of options by which it *can*, if you like, set up the *upstream* of the newly created branch name. The *default* is that if you specify a commit hash ID using a remote-tracking name (e.g., `origin/master`), that remote-tracking name becomes the upstream for the new branch name. To avoid that, change the settings (they're complicated) or use `--no-track` in your `git checkout` command.

Comment: Setting the "wrong" upstream initially like this is *mostly* harmless, unless you forget that it's set "wrong". You can fix it, right afterwards if you like, with `git branch --unset-upstream my_branch`, which just removes the upstream setting entirely. Or you can `git push -u` as above to *change* it after `git push` succeeds.